# My iphone 5's language in settings is set in english but it types in Chinese in Messages, google etc?

Tags: iphone

I just bought a refurbushed Iphone5. The language in settings is in English but when I type a text, on google or type on facebook etc it's in Mandarin/Chinese? Can anyone solve this problem! My head is wrecked haha! Thank you (谢谢)

Comment: When you text, are you seeing Chinese yourself?  Or only the recipient is seeing that?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's support article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202178

> Change the language
>
> If more than one language is on, you can change the language while typing.
> Follow these steps:
>
> - Tap  to choose the next language on your keyboard. The chosen language appears on the Space bar.
> - Touch and hold  to display a menu of enabled keyboards. Drag to choose a new keyboard.
>
> In iOS 6 and later, the language of the keyboard determines the language of the dictionary, if one is available for the language.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a Chinese keyboard to be available at all?

Į would check the Keyboard settings, right above the language within General. 
In the keyboard list add English and optionally remove any of the others you don't want.